# How to prevent clicking on posts

Tags: posts, theme-development

I have a home page that is consist of Wordpress posts. I want the posts to be static so when someone clicks the post it won't redirect to the created blog post and only will stay static.

how do I do that?

Comment: Can you  provide the website URL so I can have a look?

Comment: @Afnanabbasi Please - https://demo.accesspressthemes.com/enlighten.If you will go to "Our Courses" and click a course it will redirect you to the post itself. I would love that it will stay as is.

Comment: I have added the answer for you, But if the classes on your main site are different from the classes on your theme demo (which usually i guess will be the same though) then it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, add the following code to **WordPress Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS** :

```
.portfolio_slide_loop.wow.fadeInUp {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you need something more convenient, then use jQuery, add the following to in your **footer.php** just before the  tag. :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.portfolio_slide_loop.wow.fadeInUp').contents().unwrap();
});
</script>
```

If you still have problem in implementing one of these, you can directly [contact me](http://fiverr.com/wpcoderpro).